# Determine if POST data value matches struct field type

Tags: go, go-gin

Using the gin framework I am trying to determine if POST'ed data does not match the struct field type and inform API user of their error.

```
type CreateApp struct {
    LearnMoreImage string `db:"learn_more_image" json:"learn_more_image,omitempty" valid:"string,omitempty"`
    ApiVersion     int64  `db:"api_version" json:"api_version" valid:"int,omitempty"`
}
...
func CreateApps(c *gin.Context) {
    var json models.CreateApp
    c.Bind(&json)
```

So when I POST

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"learn_more_image":"someimage.jpg","api_version":"somestring"}' "http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1.0/apps"
```

I would like to determine whether the POST'ed data for field 'api_version' (passed as string) does not match the struct field it is being binded to (int). If the data doesnt match I'd like to send a message back to the user. Its for this reason I was hoping I could loop through the gin contexts data and check it.

The gin function 'c.Bind()' seems to omit invalid data and all subsequent data fields with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gin has a built-in validation engine: https://github.com/bluesuncorp/validator/blob/v5/baked_in.go

but you can use your own or disable it completely.

The validator does not validate the wire data (json string), instead it validates the binded struct:

```
LearnMoreImage string `db:"learn_more_image" json:"learn_more_image,omitempty" binding:"required"`
ApiVersion     int64  `db:"api_version" json:"api_version" binding:"required,min=1"`
```

Notice this: binding:"required,min=1"

Then:

```
err := c.Bind(&json)
```

or use a middleware and read `c.Errors`.

UPDATED:

Three workarounds:

- Validate the json string your own (it can not be done with enconding/json)
- Validate if integer is > 0 binding:"min=1"
- Use a map[string]interface{} instead of a Struct, then validate the type.

  ```
  func endpoint(c *gin.Context) {
      var json map[string]interface{}
      c.Bind(&json)
      struct, ok := validateCreateApp(json)
      if ok { /** DO SOMETHING */ }
  }

  func validateCreateApp(json map[string]interface{}) (CreateApp, bool) {
      learn_more_image, ok := json["learn_more_image"].(string)
      if !ok {
          return CreateApp{}, false
      }
      api_version, ok = json["api_version"].(int)
      if !ok {
          return CreateApp{}, false
      }
      return CreateApp{
          learn_more_image, api_version,
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: thank you. I tried to use c.Errors but it isnt suitable as the returned error "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int64" does not specify the field at fault.

Any tips on how to manually validate the POST data stored in the gin context?

Comment: try the map[string]interface{} approach... it sucks that the standard library does not return a better error message.